# java.lang.ClassCastException in android

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I have created an app and it was running successfully till yesterday, by today when I tried running it on my device it shows the following error in logcat and my app gets crashed.

```
03-31 12:37:47.059: ERROR/(1916): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
03-31 12:37:47.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fis.flash/com.fis.flash.FirstImage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsoluteLayout
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsoluteLayout
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at com.fis.flash.FirstImage.onCreate(FirstImage.java:106)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     ... 11 more
```

It shows an error in a `ImageView` of my  main class activity, but all the details are been correct in my coding side.

What's this error, how to over come this?

Comment: did you try a clean build and a fresh install?

Comment: You seem to use the deprecated AbsoluteLayout? Can you post the code that is causing this error.

Comment: are you sure you changed nothing in layout xml file?

Comment: I think that there is some problem with layout `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsoluteLayout 03-31 12:37:47.246: `

Comment: i had made some changes in a layout which is related to other activity...

Comment: What do you have on line 106 (and a couple of lines before) in FirstImage.java?

Comment: why does a down vote for this question nearly after 1 year?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

hi i have found my error, i have assigned linear layout in one of my xml file but i have mentioned it to be absolute layout in my class file.

Comment: can you explain please please

Answer (score 5):

ClassCastException in FirstImage class on line 106 ?
It seems you try to cast something as an AbsoluteLayout in onCreate() method where it is not.

source :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsoluteLayout 03-31 12:37:47.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916): at com.fis.flash.FirstImage.onCreate(FirstImage.java:106)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView:

I changed

```
stringsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main,myStrings);
```

To

```
stringsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,myStrings);**
```

and problem is solved for me.